# Android 32 pixel offset bug

Tags: android, graphics, 2d, android-imageview

I am working on a side scrolling game for Android like Mario or Megaman and I am having an extremely weird error that I cannot find any information on anywhere. I have my main character(an ImageView) on the screen on top of a relative view. The view only has the imageview and 3 buttons on the bottom of the screen. I move the image around the screen using setX() and setY() and the image moves correctly in the X direction, but for some reason the Y coordinates are always off by 32. Nowhere in my code is the Y value changed except for when it is initialized, and the getY() is always 32 higher than the value I assigned to it. The X value is fine. I am running it in Android 4.1. The only thing that I can think of is it being some sort of back end alignment protocol, but I can't find any information on it. Does anyone know what is causing this weird issue?

Comment: The title bar is probably 32 pixels high, right?  Are you setting FEATURE_NO_TITLE?  Is it possible that the window has a title bar which offsets the Y value by 32 pixels at the time you initialize the image, but the title bar is gone by the time you're drawing it with setY()?

Comment: Yes, I set it in the manifest with:           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"            And it is still off by 32 in the oncreate of the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the activity loads with the title bar, and then the title bar gets removed at some point shortly thereafter, so the problem might be initializing the Y value at a time when the title bar still exists.  Maybe try initializing the Y value on the first time through your onDraw function, like so:

```
public void Draw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (!yHasBeenInitialized) {
        initializeY();
        yHasBeenInitialized = true; 
    }
...
}
```

Comment: That didn't do anything different. I think that the offset is dependent on the device resolution the app is running on. When I run it on my GS3 it is 32, but when I run it on my Xoom it is only off by 16.

Comment: Huh.  Well, nothing else leaps to mind, but you might get some more answers if you post the code where you're initializing and subsequently setting Y.

Comment: I figured it out. Somehow in the XML there was padding added on the bottom and right sides of the screen and the padding on the bottom was what was changing the Y value.